# How to apply the same process to multiple csv files in pandas and save it in another directory?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been  trying to create a code, which runs through all the csv files inside the directory and applies the same operation to all of them. Afterwards it should save the new csv files in another directory.
I've got two problems: First the code only saves the last iteration and second how do I save the files with different names?

Here's my code so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dir = r'C:\my\path\to\file'
csv_files = [f for f in Path(dir).glob('*.csv')] #list all csv

for csv in csv_files: #iterate list
     df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python', delimiter = ';') #read csv
     df.drop(df.index[:-1], inplace = True) #drop all but the last row
     df.to_csv("C:\new\path\to\file\variable name") #save the file in a new dir
```

Rakesh answer works perfectly for me. Thank you guys for your input! :)

Comment: The `pathlib` library which you are already using provides a wealth of methods for manipulating filenames. Simply generate a new file name and open it for writing. Take care to create the destination directory first if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The files are being save in each iteration of loops but in the next iteration the previous file is overwritten due to same file name. So, you get only the last file saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case maybe best thing is to save new file with same name/with a common suffix or in new directory.

**I've got two problems:**

- First the code only saves the last iteration - It is because you are saving files with same name so each iteration overrides this file & only last file is available.
- and second how do I save the files with different names? - may be use same name for new files to & save in new directory or use some suffix like `mycsv_modified.csv`

Below i created an example to save in new directory (I tested this code on non-window environment & using jupyter notebook)-

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
dir_b = r'/Users/rakeshkumar/bigquery'
csv_files = [f for f in Path(dir_b).glob('*.csv')] #list all csv
#!mkdir -p processed #I created new directory to save modified file in notebook itself, you can decide yourself about new directory 
for csv in csv_files: #iterate list
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python', delimiter = ';') #read csv
    df.drop(df.index[:-1], inplace = True) #drop all but the last row
    print (df)
    df.to_csv(dir_b + "/processed/" + csv.name) #save the file in a new dir
```